# Forms is not a member of Windows

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, reference

On the following line i get error: "'Forms' is not a member of 'Windows'"

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
```

I am importing System.Windows, but cannot import System.Windows.Forms ("doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found")

I have a reference to System.Windows as well as System.Windows.Forms as shown in picture

[image]

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web

Comment: The clue might be in the product you're using. You shouldn't expect to be able to build Windows Forms applications using a "for Web" product, and if you're not building a Windows Forms application, I can't even begin to guess why you'd want to call `DoEvents()` (it's rarely the right thing to be calling when you *are* building a Windows Forms app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using VSE2k12 "for Web".

I'm not convinced that's going to include stuff explicitly marked as being for "Windows-based applications that take full advantage of the rich user interface features available in the Microsoft Windows operating system" :-)

You may need to consider getting a more expansive edition of the development environment.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [Visual Studio Express for Web](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web#product-express-web).

If you want to develop a Windows Forms application you need [Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop#product-express-desktop)

This will allow you to use `DoEvents` although the use of this is [positively discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820471/doevents-in-net)