# DoEvents() and olMail() is not declared (getting Outlook Add-In error in VSTO VisualStudio2017 )

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Im trying to develop a Outlook Add-In using VisualStudio2017 VSTO (VB Base Code). I took the basic concept (and codes) from a blog by googling for this project as im very new in VB and Add-in development.

This code works in outlook built-in vba but when ever I run this code in VisualStudio VSTO project I get two error in debugging mode which fails the execution.

## 1. DoEvents() is not declared

## 2. olMail() is not declared

I'm not sure how to solve this. I've googled for a long time but didn't get around to any solvable solution.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Ribbon

Private Sub Ribbon1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Private Sub SettingsButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles SettingsButton.Click
    Call GetAllFolders()
End Sub

Private Sub GetAllFolders()
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objSourceFolders As Outlook.Folders
    Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.Folder

    objOutlook = New Outlook.Application
    objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    'Get all the folders in a specific PST file
    objSourceFolders = objNamespace.Folders.Item("source_pst_name").Folders

    For Each objSourceFolder In objSourceFolders
        Call CopyMailsToPst(objSourceFolder)
    Next
End Sub


Sub CopyMailsToPst(ByVal objSourceFolder As Outlook.Folder)
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objDestFolderMain As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objSourceSubFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objVariant As Object
    Dim objVariantC As Object
    Dim lngMovedItems As Long
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim intDateDiff As Integer

    objOutlook = New Outlook.Application
    objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    objNamespace.AddStore("E:\pst\destnation_pst_name.pst")

    objDestFolderMain = objNamespace.Folders.Item("destnation_pst_name")
    objDestFolder = objDestFolderMain.Folders("Inbox")
    
    'olMail = objDestFolder.Items'

    For intCount = objSourceFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        objVariant = objSourceFolder.Items.Item(intCount)
        DoEvents()

        If objVariant.Class = olMail() Then

            intDateDiff = DateDiff("d", objVariant.SentOn, Now)
            If intDateDiff < 10 Then

                objVariantC = objVariant.Copy
                objVariantC.Move(objDestFolder)

                'count the # of items moved
                lngMovedItems = lngMovedItems + 1

            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Process the subfolders in the folder recursively
    If (objSourceFolder.Folders.Count > 0) Then
        For Each objSourceSubFolder In objSourceFolder.Folders
            Call CopyMailsToPst(objSourceSubFolder)
            objNamespace.RemoveStore(objDestFolderMain)
        Next
    End If

    ' Display the number of items that were moved.
    MsgBox(lngMovedItems & " Message Backed Up")
    objDestFolder = Nothing

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: (1) See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/820471/6535336) re `DoEvents`

Comment: Thanks @YowE3k, I modified `DoEvents` to `Application.DoEvents()` and now 1st error resolved. But for 2nd one, if I declare `Dim olMail As Object`  then it gives another error and asked for variable assignment. The thing is I honestly don't know why `olMail` is used here and how to assign it to which value. If `olMail` is just a variable to be assigned to any object then how it was working in outlook vba without declare or assignment

Comment: Doing a search for `olMail` very quickly led me to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/olobjectclass-enumeration-outlook) showing it is an enumeration (with a value of `43`), so definitely shouldn't have `()` after it.  Although that is VBA documentation, I assume VB.Net using VSTO will be similar.

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` _**is not**_ the solution, _multithreading_ is. Please see: [**Keeping your UI responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/)

Comment: Since it's an enum value, you should use `OlObjectClass.olMail` in VB.NET.